# How can i take date inputs from user and save it to mongoDB?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, mern

I have successfully taken date from user but after "POST" the database saves null. I've been stuck here for so long. I really need help here!! Since the date parts never got store, I didn't validate them.

This is what Database Saves

```
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("62ee76b6504db006f1bbb3d2"),
    taskName: 'hello',
    assignTo: 'world',
    startedOn: null,
    dueDate: null,
    taskDescription: 'asd',
    requiredFiles: 'asd',
    __v: 0
  }
]
```

This is my Form where User picks the date

```
function Popup(props) {
  const history = useNavigate();
  const { openPopup, setOpenPopup } = props;
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date());
  const [endDate, setDueDate] = useState(new Date());
  const [employeeName, setEmployeeName] = useState({
    taskName: "",
    assignTo: "",
    startedOn: "",
    dueDate: "",
    taskDescription: "",
    requiredFiles: "",
  });

  const clgdata = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.value);
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setEmployeeName((newData) => {
      return { ...newData, [name]: value };
    });
  };

  const changeStartDate = (newValue) =>{
    setStartDate((prev)=>{
      return{...prev, startDate : newValue}
    })
  }

  const changeDueDate = (newValue) =>{
    setDueDate((prev)=>{
      return{...prev, endDate : newValue}
    })
  }

  const createTask = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const {
      taskName,
      assignTo,
      startedOn,
      dueDate,
      taskDescription,
      requiredFiles,
    } = employeeName;

    const res = await fetch("http://localhost:3001/createtask", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "content-type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        taskName,
        assignTo,
        startedOn,
        dueDate,
        taskDescription,
        requiredFiles,
      }),
    });
    const data = await res.json();
    console.log(data);
    if (res.status === 404 || !data) {
      alert("Please Complete the Empty Fields");
    } else {
      alert(`Task has been assigned to the employee`);
      setOpenPopup(false);
      history("/task");
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Dialog open={openPopup}>
        <DialogTitle>
          <div className="title">
            <ArrowBackIcon
              className="leftArrow"
              onClick={() => setOpenPopup(false)}
            >
              close
            </ArrowBackIcon>

            <h3>Create a task</h3>
          </div>
        </DialogTitle>
        <DialogContent>
          <div className="form">
            <TextField
              className="form-btn"
              name="taskName"
              type="text"
              id="outlined-basic"
              label="Task Title"
              variant="outlined"
              onChange={clgdata}
              value={employeeName.taskName}
            />
            <TextField
              name="assignTo"
              type="text"
              onChange={clgdata}
              value={employeeName.assignTo}
              className="form-btn"
              id="outlined-basic"
              label="Select an Employee"
            ></TextField>
            <div className="Time">
              <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
                <DatePicker
                  name="startedOn"
                  className="form-btn startedOn"
                  label="Started On"
                  type="date"
                  value={startDate.startDate}
                  onChange={changeStartDate}
                  renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
                />
              </LocalizationProvider>
              <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
                <DatePicker
                  className="form-btn startedOn"
                  name="dueDate"
                  label="Due Date"
                  value={endDate.endDate}
                  onChange={changeDueDate}
                  renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
                />
              </LocalizationProvider>
            </div>
 </div>
            <TextField
              className="form-btn"
              id="outlined-basic"
              label="Task Description"
              variant="outlined"
              name="taskDescription"
              type="text"
              onChange={clgdata}
              value={employeeName.taskDescription}
            />
            <TextField
              className="form-btn"
              id="outlined-basic"
              label="Required Files"
              variant="outlined"
              name="requiredFiles"
              type="text"
              onChange={clgdata}
              value={employeeName.requiredFiles}
            />
          </div>
        </DialogContent>
        <DialogActions>
          <Button onClick={createTask}>Submit</Button>
        </DialogActions>
      </Dialog>
    </>
  );
}

export default Popup;
```

This is my userSchema of MongoDB

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  taskName: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  assignTo: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,

  },
  startedOn: {
    type: Date,
    // required: true,
  },
  dueDate: {
    type: Date,
    // required: true,
  },
  taskDescription:{
      type: String,
      required: true,
  },
  requiredFiles:{
      type: String,
      required: true,
  }
});

const createTask = mongoose.model("createTask", userSchema);

module.exports = createTask;
```

This is my router.JS

```
router.post("/createtask", async (req, res) => {
 const {
    taskName,
    assignTo,
    startedOn,
    dueDate,
    taskDescription,
    requiredFiles,
  } = req.body;

  if (!taskName || !assignTo || !taskDescription || !requiredFiles) {
    res.status(404).json("Please Complete the Empty Fields");
  } else {
    const newTask = new createTask({
      taskName,
      assignTo,
      startedOn,
      dueDate,
      taskDescription,
      requiredFiles,
    });

    await newTask.save();
    res.status(201).json(newTask);
    console.log(newTask);
  }
});
```

Comment: Tip: at each step of the execution flow, log the values 'startedOn' and 'dueDate', test and see at exactly what part of the flow you are actually 'losing' this information. Then go back one step, and check what is happening in the previous step. This is the part of the code that is probably mishandling the data and doesn't pass it to the next part.

Comment: Yes sir you are right, 

I found the place where it is not being passed forward. 
Right when the createTask function triggers other values are passed but dates are not passed 

Before that i've consoled the logs it worked. and I couldn't find how to solve it , that's the reason I'm here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several inconsistencies in your code.

Remove these two lines:

```
const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date());
const [endDate, setDueDate] = useState(new Date());
```

Update the initialization:

```
const [employeeName, setEmployeeName] = useState({
  taskName: "",
  assignTo: "",
  startedOn: new Date(),
  dueDate: new Date(),
  taskDescription: "",
  requiredFiles: "",
});
```

Update the handlers:

```
const changeStartDate = (newValue) => {
  setEmployeeName((prev) => {
    return { ...prev, startedOn: newValue };
  });
};

const changeDueDate = (newValue) => {
  setEmployeeName((prev) => {
    return { ...prev, dueDate: newValue };
  });
};
```

Update the DatePickers:

```
<LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
    <DatePicker
        name="startedOn"
        className="form-btn startedOn"
        label="Started On"
        type="date"
        value={employeeName.startedOn}
        onChange={changeStartDate}
        renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
    />
    </LocalizationProvider>
    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
    <DatePicker
        className="form-btn startedOn"
        name="dueDate"
        label="Due Date"
        value={employeeName.dueDate}
        onChange={changeDueDate}
        renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
    />
</LocalizationProvider>
```

Now `createTask` sends `startedOn` and `dueDate` to the server.